# Android - Facebook Graph API - not able to get AccessToken

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I'm trying to fetch Data from a Facebook page and in the Graph Explorer I'm doing just fine. I am using a global app Token.

[image]

I am able to fetch data here. So now I'm trying to do following:

```
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            accessToken,
            "/<-pageid->/posts",
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    // Insert your code here
                }
            });

    request.executeAsync();
}
```

But i just don't know how to create the Access Token as java Object.

```
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
```

is returning null in my case. I called following code in the beginning:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
```

And did everything in the API Quickstart guide.

I tried to initialize a new Object of AccessToken, but I'm missing so many parameters and filling null didn't work out well. I just have an AppToken as String fetched as json from the graph api and a UserToken. How to achieve getting the AccessToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with a little workaround for everyone reading the question:
I didn't use the Facebook Android SDK, I just sent an GET-Request via my android app to fetch the json data and get it into my controller. I used following code:

```
public class FacebookController {

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl() throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/<page_id>/posts?limit=100&access_token=<my-access-token>").openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Do not forget to wrap it in an AsyncTask when using it.